# Angular 1.x - creating custom attribute directives with assignment

Tags: angularjs

In angular I know how to create custom directives that have the following syntax:

**Element directive**

```
<my-custom-element attr1 = "some stuff"> </my-custom-element>
```

**Attribute directive**

```
<div my-custom-attribute> </div>
```

---

**What I want to do**

```
<div my-custom-attribute = "some value"> </div>
```

Is this possible?

If so, how? 
I would appreciate a minimalist example.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have both named same,

```
app.directive('myCustomAttribute', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myCustomAttribute: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '...'
    };
});
```

which can be used as,

```
<div my-custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

[**sample working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LZRSBoudi66Y8WCvC9yk?p=preview)